# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0-3000

Tags: php

```
<?php  
include('http://pvilks.progpamati.lv/PHP_07/dati.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if(isset($_POST['sort'])&&$_POST['sort']==1)
    {
        $time=microtime(true); //uznem laiku
        $pass=false;
        while($pass==false)
        {
            $pass=true;
            for($numbers=0;$numbers<3000;$numbers++)
            {
                if($numberArray[$numbers]>$numberArray[$numbers+1])
                {
                $temp=$numberArray[$numbers];
                $numberArray[$numbers]=$numberArray[$numbers+1];
                $numberArray[$numbers+1]=$temp;
                $pass=false;
                }
            }
        }
    echo "<br>Bubble sort algoritms strādā, izpildot savu doto funkciju ". (microtime(true)-$time) . " sekundēs. <br>";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['sort'])&&$_POST['sort']==2)
    {
        $laiks=microtime(true);
        $pass=false;
        while($pass==false)
        {
            $pass=true;
            for($words=0;$<100;$words++)
            {
                $p=0;
                $n=substr($wordArray[$words],$p,1);
                $nplusone=substr($wordArray[$words+1],$p,1);
                while($n==$onplusone)
                {
                    $p++;
                    $n=substr($wordArray[$words],$p,1);
                    $nplusone=substr($wordArray[$words+1],$p,1);
                }
                if($n>$nplusone)
                {
                    $temp=$wordArray[$i];
                    $wordArray[$words]=$wordArray[$words+1];
                    $wordArray[$words+1]=$temp;
                    $pass=false;
                }
            }
        }
        echo "<br>Bubble sort algoritms strādā, izpildot savu doto funkciju ". (microtime(true)-$time)*30 . " sekundēs. <br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Error log spits out 3000 errors all the same saying

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 on line 14

which is

```
if($numberArray[$numbers]>$numberArray[$numbers+1])
```

I'm clueless as to what's the problem. There are no colons missing (I'm pretty sure).

Comment: Where is `$numberArray` defined? What does it contain? `print_r($numberArray)`

Comment: $numberArray is defined in the php file which is added at the start (include('dati.php'))

Comment: You are adding via `http`, not as a file, so that is run through the server and processed. Is that intended? Does `print_r` give output?

Comment: it is intended to run through a server and `print_r` doesn't give an output

Comment: I meant `http://pvilks.progpamati.lv/PHP_07/dati.php` is running through the `http://pvilks.progpamati.lv` server. So a file such as `<?php $hello_world = 'hi'; echo $hello_world;` that was included via `http` would just have `hi` in it but included as a path the execution would output `hi` still but the `$hello_world` would also be defined. You expect the first file to be rendered and outputted?

Comment: yeah that cleared up things, I was supposed to only `include('dati.php');`